# NullPointerException: when set TextView value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a layout file(`layout/my_test.xml`):

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/my_title"
      android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />
```

My Activity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private View myTestView;    
    private TextView actionBarTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
       super.onCreate(arg0);

       myTestView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_test, null);
       myTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_title);

       //NullPointerException here !!
       myTitle.setText(getString(R.string.hello));
    }
}
```

(I am sure the problem is not about the `res/strings.xml` , because the "hello" string resource has been used in other place which is fine.)

**Why** I got **NullPointerException** when I set the `TextView` content ??

The full error trace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(17283):    at com.test.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(17283):    at com.eficode.card.CardActivity.onCreate(CarActivity.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime(17283):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(17283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
E/AndroidRuntime(17283):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: you are not setting any thing to be displayed on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create Textview id as follows  **myTitle = (TextView) myTestView .findViewById(R.id.my_title)**;

Comment: Hi! Thanks, it is fine now. But can you explain why I can not directly use findViewById in Activity?

Answer (score 0):

you should write your onCreate correctly because you are not setting any thing to be displayed on screen:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
       super.onCreate(arg0);
       setContentView(R.layout.my_test);

       myTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_title);

       myTitle.setText(getString(R.string.hello));
    }
```

Comment: No, I can't agree with you, because Activity do not have to setContent always. My code works fine after I use @ Venkata Krishna 's answer.

Comment: yes, you may keep your activity blank but then whats even the point of TextView in your activity if you dont want it to be shown anywhere? and this is what android-developer says: `An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View).`

Answer (score 0):

you can only get the id's  directly for views in layout that is declared in setcontentView(R.layout.your_layout_id);  but when you inflate some layout then you have to get ids of the views in the inflated view as follows view_id.find....();